# Draw a square inside another

Tags: c

i am trying to create that a program prints the following figure

```
000000
011110
010010
011110
000000
```

I made this little code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, j, side;

    printf("Enter side: ");
    scanf("%d", &side);

    for( j = 0; j < side; j++ )
    {
      for( i = 0; i < side; i++ )
         if((i*j == 0) || ((i*j)%side==0)) //as should be the condition here
            printf("0");
         else
            printf("1");
    printf("\n");
    }     
    return 0;       
}
```

which does not print what I want the question is in the condition of **if** I don't know how it should be i'm not good at math. Can someone help me with this little problem?

**edited**

for example

entry: 8

output:

```
00000000
01111110
01000010
01000010
01000010
01111110
00000000
```

Comment: If it's supposed to draw squares, why does your example output show rectangles?

Comment: If the figure you need is exactly the one on the example, then you don't need to make an algorithm to decide whether to print a `1` or a `0`, what you need is to store the values in an array, if you need a generic algorithm **Rizier123**'s solution might or might not work for you.

Comment: You need to explain what exactly the program should do. It isn't clear what the output should be with other sizes. It also isn't clear why the output isn't a square.

Comment: Now you have given another example can we say the "square" has dimension `x = y + 1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here i just simple search for the smallest number of: `rows(side - 1)`, `columns(side)`, `rowCount(j)`, `columnCount(i)` and then `i` use the modulo operator to get either `0` or `1`)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int min(int x, int y) {
    return (x < y ?x:y);
}

int main() {    
    int i, j, side;

    printf("Enter side: ");
    scanf("%d", &side);

    for( j = 1; j < side; j++ ) {
        for( i = 1; i <= side; i++ )
            printf("%d", (min(i - 1, min(j - 1, min(side - j - 1, side - i)))) % 2);        
        printf("\n");
    }    
    return 0;    
}
```

Input:

```
6
```

Output:

```
000000
011110
010010
011110
000000
```

**EDIT:**

If you only want 1 square with 1's and after that all filled with 0's, then this should work for you:

(Here i just simple check if it is the second square and if yes print 1 else print 0)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int min(int x, int y) {
    return (x < y ?x:y);
}

int main() {
    int i, j, side;

    printf("Enter side: ");
    scanf("%d", &side);

    for( j = 1; j < side; j++ ) {
        for( i = 1; i <= side; i++ )
            if(min(i - 1, min(j - 1, min(side - j - 1, side - i))) == 1)
                printf("1");
            else
                printf("0");
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
6  // 8
```

Output:

```
000000  // 00000000
011110  // 01111110
010010  // 01000010
011110  // 01000010
000000  // 01000010
        // 01111110
        // 00000000
```

Comment: Because it's wrong (it will probably show strange shapes for larger sizes), and because it has no explanation. There's no point in just solving someone's homework for them. The real question is why someone upvoted a block-of-code answer that isn't even correct.

Comment: @interjay overlooked something, now it should be correct, also tried to explain what i'm doing here

Comment: @Rizier123 I upvoted because the downvote  didn't make much sense to me, but your answer could be the answer, but not necessarily. Although it does generate the sample output.

Comment: I guess this might be what OP intended, now that I look at the question again. It doesn't just "draw a square inside another" but draws many squares, but may be what OP wants.

Comment: @CooperJames it's your fault, because you should add an example with `side > 6`, since the solution would be different.

Comment: @CooperJame please say where it doesn't work. (e.g. input and expected output)

Comment: @CooperJames So if i see it right you only want once to print a square with 1's and after that only fill it with 0's ?

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed the `if` try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static inline int isValid(int i, int j, int side)
{
    return (((i == 1) || (i == side - 2)) && ((j != 0) && (j != side - 1)));
}

int main(void)
{
    int i, j, side;

    printf("Enter side: ");
    scanf("%d", &side);

    for (j = 0 ; j < side ; j++)
    {
        for (i = 0 ; i < side ; i++)
        {
            if ((isValid(i, j, side) != 0) || (isValid(j, i, side) != 0))
                printf("1");
            else
                printf("0");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You only need to check if `i == 1` since it's the second row/column or if `i == side - 2` since that will be the pre-last row/column the same for `j`, to prevent drawing a cross on the corners, you need to check that if `i == 1` then `j != 0` and if `i == side - 2` then `j != side - 1`.

You can of course do this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, j, side;

    printf("Enter side: ");
    scanf("%d", &side);

    /* print first row all 0's */
    for (j = 0 ; j < side ; j++)
        printf("0");
    printf("\n");

    for (j = 1 ; j < side - 1 ; j++)
    {
        /* print first column 0 always */
        printf("0");
        if ((j == 1) || (j == side - 2))
        {   /*                       ^ this is because the loops start at 0 */
            /* this is the second of side - 1 row */
            for (i = 1 ; i < side - 1 ; i++)
                printf("1");
        }
        else
        {
            /* if the column is the second or it's the (side - 1)th print 1, otherwise 0 */
            for (i = 1 ; i < side - 1 ; i++)
                printf(((i == 1) || (i == side - 2)) ? "1" : "0");
        }

        if (i == side - 2)
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");

        printf("\n");
    }

    /* print last row all 0's */
    for (j = 0 ; j < side ; j++)
        printf("0");
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem right, and even if it was you should explain it. These multiplications and modulos are completely unnecessary, and seem to be nothing more than obfuscation as they can be replaced by simple comparisons (e.g. `(1+i) % side == 0`  --> `i == side-1`).

Comment: @iharob: does not print the two zeros in the center

Comment: They're not, it's perfectly valid to think about that, of course they're not really needed, but since it's not possible to know what the OP is really trying to do, then this answers the OP's question.

Comment: @CooperJames i didn't see them, I will delete this answer. But also, you should then use a different example, because it's not possible to know the width of the `1`'s in the figure, if you don't need a generic algorithm, then store the values in an array and print it using a loop.